# Detecting EOF with fgets() where filesteam is stdin

Tags: c, null, eof, fgets

Bit of background, I'm writing a program that plays the game "boxes" it runs in linux command line and is written in C. There's a prompt that waits for user input and then is read with fgets() and interpretted etc.

As part of the task specification I have to return a specific error if I reach "End of file while waiting for user input". I understand that fgets() returns null when it reaches EOF... but say I have

`fgets(input,max_buffer,stdin);`

in a prompt loop if the user exits prematurely say with CTRL+C or CTRL+D does this mean that input == NULL?

Can I even detect when a user does this with fgets?

Just trying to get my head around this, thanks in advance for any help.

(OS: UNIX) 
(Compiler: gcc - c90)

Comment: Ctl-C kills the program, so `fgets` never returns. Ctl-D causes an end of file condition. `man fgets`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/), `fgets`:

> Reads characters from stream and stores them as a C string into str until (num-1) characters have been read or either a newline or the end-of-file is reached, whichever happens first.
>
> A newline character makes fgets stop reading, but it is considered a valid character by the function and included in the string copied to str.
>
> A terminating null character is automatically appended after the characters copied to str.

So, `fgets` will return when the user inputs CTRL-D (end-of-file) *or*, when a `\n` (newline) is encountered. CTRL-C will *by default* terminate your program entirely.

If you'd like to catch CTRL-C, and exit gracefully, you could:

```
#include <signal.h>

void intHandler(int dummy) {
    //graceful CTRL-C exit code.
}

int main(void) {
    signal(SIGINT, intHandler);
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Technically, it's a mistake to say that Control-C terminates your program. It *can*, but this is only the default behavior and can be changed as you demonstrate. SIGTERM and SIGKILL are specifically designed to kill a process, with SIGKILL being almost guaranteed to work since it cannot be blocked or ignored.

Comment: @SevenBits, thank you for your response to my oversight.  My answer has been updated to reflect your point.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation (C99 §7.19.7.2):

> The fgets function returns *s* if successful. If end-of-file is encountered and no characters have been read into the array, the contents of the array remain unchanged and a null pointer is returned. If a read error occurs during the operation, the array contents are indeterminate and a null pointer is returned.

So if an end-of-file occurs, but characters have been read, `fgets` will not return `NULL`. If EOF happens before any input was read, it will return `NULL`.

You can differentiate between EOF and a read error with the [`feof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/feof) and [`ferror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ferror) functions.

Answer (score 1):

When the end-user exits permanently with Ctrl+C, your program loses control right away, meaning that you do not get any further input from fgets, not even a NULL.

Ctrl+D, on the other hand, closes the input stream without closing your program, so you would get a NULL result from the fgets call.

You can set your program up to handle Ctrl+C by handling a signal, but such handling would happen outside the input loop.

Comment: I was under the impression that If an error occurs, a null pointer is returned, or would control-c not be considered an error.

Comment: @l'L'l Ctrl+C is not an I/O error, it is handled out of bound as a signal to close the process.

Comment: Ah, okay... I must of been having flashbacks to the Ascii [ETX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-text_character) days! :)